# merge more then one collection in mongodb & perform sort on it

Tags: mongodb, sorting, collections, merge

I have collections `products`, `company` & `package`.

`company` has a reference to `package` which specify its package
& `product` has a reference to `company`.

When I list the products of all companies the sorting order will be based on the package selected by the company. Collection `package` has a field `sortingOrder`. The company whose package is higher should have its products come first in the list.

What I tried: I used mapreduce but I was unable to perform sort on it.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried?

Comment: There aren't joins in MongoDb. You need to rethink your data model or do the sorting on the client.